# SpriteKit/Objective-C: Applying SKPhysicsBody to parent node so it treats child nodes as one

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an SKNode that is has two child SKShapeNodes.

```
+(instancetype)skeetWithRandomColorsAtPosition:(CGPoint)position WithSize:(CGFloat)size {

InnerSkeetNode *inner = [InnerSkeetNode innerSkeetWithHue:PurpleHue AtPosition:position WithSize:size];
OuterSkeetNode *outer = [OuterSkeetNode outerSkeetWithHue:BlueHue AtPosition:position WithSize:size];

SkeetNode *skeetnode = [SkeetNode node];
[skeetnode addChild:outer];
[skeetnode addChild:inner];

[skeetnode setUpPhysicsBody];

return skeetnode;
}
```

...so basically the parent node is made up of two shapes -- inner and outer -- of different colours.

Now I want to apply a physics body to skeetnode:

```
-(void)setUpPhysicsBody {
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody    
bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.frame.size];
self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
}
```

…but the problem is that it remains unaffected by the game's physics world.

However, the two child nodes will be affected if I set up physics bodies on them separately. The problem is, they act as two bodies. For collision purposes, I want to treat them as a single node -- hence adding them to the parent.

There's SKPhysicsJointFixed. But, after trying it out (and according to the documentation) I can only add the joint to a scene, not to a discrete node.

Is it possible to add to children to an SKNode and treat them as one physics body? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's because you are using self when creating a physics body and this case self is the SKNode which has no shape by itself. Try using SKShapeNode and adding a child to it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, sangony. I double checked and found skeetnode.physicsBody was nil.

So I inherited SKSkeetNode from SKSpriteNode and created an instance this way:

```
SkeetNode *skeetnode = [SkeetNode spriteNodeWithTexture:nil size:CGSizeMake(size, size)];
```

Now it works perfectly.